# Adding new column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would need to manage a data frame by adding more columns. 
My sample of data headers is

```
`Date` `Sentence` 
28 Jan      who.c   
30 Jan      house.a
02 Feb      eurolet.it
```

I would need to add another column, `Tp`, that for each link assigns a value:

- if a sentence ends with `a` then assign `apartment`; if it ends with `b` then assign `bungalow` and so on as shown in `original`;
- if a sentence ends with `UK` then assign `United Kingdom`; if it ends with `IT` then assign `Italy`, and so on. Values are from `country`. 
  I would expect something like this:

  Date       Sentence       Tp
  28 Jan      who.c        church
  30 Jan      house.a      apartment
  02 Feb      eurolet.it.  Italy

I wrote the following:

```
conditions = [df['Sentence'].str.endswith(original), df['Sentence'].str.endswith(country)]
choices = [original, country]
# df['Tp'] = df.apply(lambda row: urlparse(row['Sentence']).netloc, axis = 1)
df['Tp'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default ='Unknown')
print(df)
```

where

```
original= [('a', 'apartment'), ('b', 'bungalow'), ('c', 'church')]
```

and

```
country = [('UK', 'United Kingdom'), ('IT', 'Italy'), ('DE', 'Germany'), ('H', 'Holland'), ..., ('F', 'France'), ('S', 'Spain')]
```

`country` contains more than 50 elements.

Could you tell me how to fix it? The column should be added in the data frame, then to a csv file.

Thanks

Update:

```
                      Sentences  \
    0                                      
    1                       who.c  
    2                  citta.me.it   
    3                    office.of
    4                   eurolet.eu   
    ..                               ...   
    995                    uilpa.ie   
    996                      fog.de

Original and country are from

list_country=np.array(country).tolist()
list_country_name=np.array(country_name).tolist()
flat_name_country = [item for sublist in list_country for item in sublist]
flat_country_name = [item for sublist in list_country_name for item in sublist] 

zip_domains=list(zip(flat_name_country, flat_country_name))
```

Comment: please add some sample input data to your post. [mcve]

Comment: I added some sample input. However I think it was already reproducible. I do not understand why to give my question a score down only for that. People that look at score to answer questions may are not interested in answering low scored question. And people that ask questions look for some help..

Comment: your question was not reproducible at all as you failed to provide any sample data hence my downvote. good reproducible answers get quality answers fairly quickly. Can you confirm that the last item in Sentence is always preceded by a fullstop ?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it. I just added the expected output too.

Comment: I would be interested in ending sentence, from the full stop to the end (e.g. for `house.a` I would look at `.a`; for `street.euv` at `.eur`, and so on). Then, I would need to associate the words apartment, Europe, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets make some dictionaries from your tuples and combine them

```
country = {k.lower() : v for (k,v) in country}
og = {k : v for (k,v) in original}
country.update(og)

print(country)

{'uk': 'United Kingdom',
 'it': 'Italy',
 'de': 'Germany',
 'h': 'Holland',
 'f': 'France',
 's': 'Spain',
 'a': 'apartment',
 'b': 'bungalow',
 'c': 'church'}
```

then lets split and get the max element - this allows for any full stops in your text to be ignored, only looking at the final element. finally, we use `.map` to associate your values.

```
df['value'] = df["Sentence"].str.split(".", expand=True).stack().reset_index(1).query(
    "level_1 == level_1.max()"
)[0].map(country)

print(df)

     Date    Sentence      value
0  28 Jan       who.c     church
1  30 Jan     house.a  apartment
2  02 Feb  eurolet.it      Italy
```

Comment: thank you datanovise.. However it is still returning unknown and NaN values.

Comment: @math.world you need exact matches - if it returns `NaN` then it has no match.

Answer (score 1):

Can you convert your `original` and `country` into dict ?

```
original= [('a', 'apartment'), ('b', 'bungalow'), ('c', 'church')]
original = {x:y for x,y in original}
country = [('UK', 'United Kingdom'), ('IT', 'Italy'), ('DE', 'Germany'), ('H', 'Holland'), ..., ('F', 'France'), ('S', 'Spain')]
country = {x:y for x,y in country}
```

Now you can perform the same task as :

```
df['Tp'] = df['Sentence'].apply(lambda sen : original.get( sen[-1], country.get(sen[-1], 'unknown') ) )
```

In your code, you need to have the length of elements in `conditions` to be same as in `choices` (and by extension original and country)

Comment: thank you Spandan. Unfortunately I got the following error after applying to my dataset: `IndexError: string index out of range`. Otherwise I get only unknown value

Comment: Can you show more details for error ? Which line and what exact error ?