# Create a new column (data frame) based on suffix of its items

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset built using pandas:

```
    URLS  \
0

1                   www.gene.eu   
2  www.cittametropolitana.me.it   
3     www.regione.basilicata.it   
4    www.bbc.co.uk   

                                               Paths  
0                                                     
1            /news-room/q-a-detail/ 
2                     /emergenza-sanitari/  
3                     /giunta/site/giunta/detail.jsp  
4  /focus/
```

And I would like to check the suffix of each URLS (eu, it, co.uk,...) assigning one of these values:

```
suffix=['.it','.uk','.eu'] # this should be used as set which includes all the suffix that I want to check
country=['Italy','United Kingdom','Europe'] # values to assign based on the suffix

zipped = list(zip(suffix, country)) # create a connection between suffix and country
```

I have tried in several ways, thanks also a couple of users that have helped me with this problem) to add this new column with suffix information in my data frame sample, but without success (please find here a question related to this problem with a different sample: [Adding new column with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61002428/adding-new-column-with-condition/61003438?noredirect=1#comment107934115_61003438)):

```
country = {k.lower() : v for (k,v) in zipped}
og = {k : v for (k,v) in suffix}
country.update(og)
# (1)
df['value'] = df['URLS'].str.split(".", expand=True).stack().reset_index(1).query(
    "level_1 == level_1.max()"
)[0].map(country)

# (2)
original_domain = {x: y for x, y  in zipped}

df['value'] = df['URLS'].apply(lambda sen : original_domain.get( sen[-1], 'Unknown') ) )

# (3)
df['value']=df['URLS'].map(lambda x: x[-3:] in zipped) 

#(4)
df['value'] = np.where(df['URLS'].str.endswith(suffix), pd.to_datetime(df['value'])) # it returns me errors and t needs another step to assign country
```

but none of these pieces of code works. URLS is a column derived by parsing the links. I think the problem can be in defining value column from a calculated item, without creating a list, so I would need to create it depending on URLS. 
So I would like to ask you how to add this new columns, looking for suffix ending and assigning a corresponding value (Italy, United Kingdom, ...).

I hope you can help me.

Thanks

**Edit:**

`df` is defined as follows:

```
df=pd.read_csv('path/text.csv', sep=';', engine='python')
```

I think this can cause an error when I try to apply the code proposed by *sK500*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go if I understood correctly:

```
import pandas as pd


suffix = ['it', 'uk', 'eu']
country = ['Italy', 'United Kingdom', 'Europe']
mapping = dict(zip(suffix, country))
urls = ['www.gene.eu', 'www.cittametropolitana.me.it', 'www.regione.basilicata.it', 'www.bbc.co.uk']
paths = ['/news-room/q-a-detail/', '/emergenza-sanitari/', '/giunta/site/giunta/detail.jsp', '/focus/']
frame = pd.DataFrame(zip(urls, paths), columns=['urls', 'paths'])
for ext in mapping:
    frame.loc[frame['urls'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.')[-1]) == ext, 'Country'] = mapping[ext]
print(frame)
```

Out:

```
                           urls                           paths         Country
0                   www.gene.eu          /news-room/q-a-detail/          Europe
1  www.cittametropolitana.me.it            /emergenza-sanitari/           Italy
2     www.regione.basilicata.it  /giunta/site/giunta/detail.jsp           Italy
3                 www.bbc.co.uk                         /focus/  United Kingdom
```

and note that in order for this to work properly, you need to add all extensions you want to include in the mapping beforehand and the data must be uniform(you have to make sure that every url has a `.` and ends with an extension included in the mapping otherwise you'll get `nan` values which you wouldn't want.

Comment: Thank you so much sK500. I applied what you suggested but I am getting only NaN as value. No errors. Do you know why? I tried your code and it works fine with the sample that I provided

Comment: so, it solves the problem/ does not solve the problem?

Comment: Since I have also the links, not only the urls, I tried with the urls and probably is returning me NaN as they do not finish with ._ but with path. So I tried with urls, as you shown,  and I got the following error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. But urls is a column as it is there when I run `df.columns`

Comment: but that's not what I included in my answer

Comment: yes, I know. I thought it could work but it does not.  `df['URLS']` is the parsed netloc of links (in my question I mentioned that URLS is a column derived by parsing the links) . I do not know why it could not work and it gives my that error.

Comment: I think the problem due to the error is because a few lines are : `1123                           b''   
1124                           b''   
1125                           b''   
1126                                 
1127                           b''  ` and I defined df as `df=pd.read_csv('path/text.csv', sep=';', engine='python')`

Comment: you should've provided a valid sample and as this is deviating from the initial question scope I will not be answering this.

Comment: Ok sK500. I have appreciated your help and your time spent to help me. By the way, it is caused because of the `df` definition not about how I calculated the column as it should have worked. How should have I known?

Comment: you're welcome man, no code matches all purposes, it always needs some tailoring according to your needs, just make sure that the data fits the conditions specified in whatever code you use beforehand in order to avoid such problems.